# What is the difference between running a vertx verticle and deploying a verticle through another verticle container?

Tags: vert.x

```
{ vertx run vertcle1.groovy}

{container.deployVerticle("verticle1.groovy"}
```

What happens in the background when these two statements are executed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1st command runs another JVM

2nd loads verticle in a separate classloader but inside current vertx process

Comment: why don't the separate verticles share a classloader?

Comment: it was in Vertx 2.x.
Classes are shared by default in Vertx 3.x

> By default, Vert.x has a flat classpath. I.e, when Vert.x deploys verticles it does so with the current classloader - it doesn’t create a new one. In the majority of cases this is the simplest, clearest, and sanest thing to do.

https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_verticle_isolation_groups

Comment: I suppose if different vertx verticles is running on different machines/hardware, then can't share classes etc